# No plugin found for prefix 'gluonfx' + causing gluon mobile and javafx code to not be recognized

Tags: javafx, maven-2, gluon-mobile

I have been following https://foojay.io/today/creating-mobile-apps-with-javafx-part-2/, but when I got to the step with `$ mvn -Pios gluonfx:build`,  Unfortunately, that does not work for me because as soon as I delete the .m2 file, it reappears.

Edit: help! Any line of code on my Gluon-Mobile project (on Netbeans) relating to JavaFx or Gluon (I.e. label nodes, import statements, and almost everything) has errors now! I do not know what I did because it was working perfectly earlier today. I am very concerned. please help!

Errors when creating an account/logging in (I had to put them on a Google Doc since the question was too long)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rqe8jEMNQY9gUvzwuqwHnzDoyTEVMbVPia8sWOyYLww/edit?usp=sharing

new(?) error:

```
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] determineCpuFeaures
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Aug 07, 2021 5:01:49 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @18b7c82f'
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 0 view 0 pf otready 
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 Metal - 68.8
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]   initialize() returns 4557157648
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 812ce820 view 0 pf otready 
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 Metal - 68.8
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO vendor
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO renderer
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO glExtensions
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO allocate the structure
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO set function pointers
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 812ce820 view 0 pf otready 
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 Metal - 68.8
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO vendor
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO renderer
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO glExtensions
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO allocate the structure
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] CTXINFO set function pointers
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] 414.000000 896.000000
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] 2021-08-07 17:01:50.048625-0700 Therabot[17616:1514744] [AttachLog] Notch is UNKNOWN
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] [AttachLog] 2021-08-07 17:01:50.049 void sendNotch():149 Notch is UNKNOWN
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Aug 07, 2021 5:01:50 PM com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.license.LicenseManager validateLicense
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] INFO: Validation of license key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX completed, Valid license.file exists.
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Aug 07, 2021 5:01:53 PM com.mysecondapplication.views.PrimaryView <init>
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] SEVERE: null
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/newbackground.png (No such file or directory)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_io_FileNotFoundException_2_0002e_0003cinit_0003e_00028Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(FileInputStream.java)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.mysecondapplication.views.PrimaryView.<init>(PrimaryView.java:73)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.CachedFactory.get(CachedFactory.java:32)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.doSwitchView(MobileApplication.java:723)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(MobileApplication.java:477)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(MobileApplication.java:452)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.SplashView.hideSplashView(SplashView.java:215)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.SplashView.lambda$defaultTransitionEventHandler$2(SplashView.java:234)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.Animation.runHandler(Animation.java:1102)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.Animation.finished(Animation.java:1096)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.AnimationAccessorImpl.finished(AnimationAccessorImpl.java:49)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.SingleLoopClipEnvelope.timePulse(SingleLoopClipEnvelope.java:107)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.Animation.doTimePulse(Animation.java:1189)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.Animation$1.lambda$timePulse$0(Animation.java:207)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:100)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.animation.Animation$1.timePulse(Animation.java:206)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractPrimaryTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractPrimaryTimer.java:343)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractPrimaryTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractPrimaryTimer.java:266)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:570)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:554)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:547)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VARARGS:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] 
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] 2021-08-07 17:01:56.119584-0700 Therabot[17616:1514744] [AttachLog] Notch is TOP
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] [AttachLog] 2021-08-07 17:01:56.120 void sendNotch():149 Notch is TOP
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Creating file: ./hi-470529521.dat
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] IOException in btn; log in
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.mysecondapplication.views.PrimaryView.lambda$new$1(PrimaryView.java:228)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3880)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1873)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2606)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:100)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
[Sat Aug 07 17:02:08 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB]  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
```

Comment: The message error is quite clear: `"there is no POM in this directory (/Users/superpengooooo). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory". You are not running from the project folder.

Comment: Ok, I can do that, thanks @JoséPereda. But how did I manage to cause so many errors in my project, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried running the terminal from the project folder location, but still received the same error.

Comment: In order to help you we need more information. Edit the  post and add your OS  (I take MacOS), Java/JavaFX version, GluonFX plugin version,. If possible describe your project structure and how do you run it (IDE or terminal, from root folder) Also does `mvn javafx:run` work?

Comment: Done! Thank you @JoséPereda

Comment: Ok, so now `mvn gluonfx:run` should work as well. And `mvn gluonfx:build` too (creating a native image for Mac). Try it first before building for iOS.

Comment: @JoséPereda both of those commands have the same `No plugin found for prefix 'gluonfx'` error, even though the terminal is being run from the project file.

Comment: Try gluonfx plugin 1.0.3?

Comment: How do I update the plugin? I'm not seeing any options to update.

Comment: Edit the pom file and you can apply the changes to the different properties

Comment: Ok, so I tried editing the version on line 7: `<version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>`, which did not do anything. I also tried editing client plugin version on line 16: `<client.plugin.version>1.0.3</client.plugin.version>`, which also did nothing.

Comment: Make sure you use *gluonfx* and not *client* plugin, and version 1.0.3 (without snapshot). Since I don’t see your pom, I can’t see the lines you are referring to.

Comment: Ok, I have put the contents of the pom file in my question. I haven't changed it since it auto-generated for me when I first made the project. I think I see the problem, though; I don't seem to have a gluonfx plugin in my pom file. How do I add it?

Comment: Edit the pom and replace `client` with `gluonfx`. Save it and try again. By the way, what is the Gluon plugin version for your IDE?

Comment: Looks like you are running an old version of the Gluon plugin for NetBeans. Check in `Tools->Plugins` that you have the latest (2.8.3) and upgrade it if you don't.

Comment: @JoséPereda still no luck. I'm receiving the same error. I'm not sure what you mean by the version for my IDE; the version statement I put in the project description was obtained through the NetBeans plugin portal.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm not being given an option to upgrade the Gluon plugin. It still says 1.0.

Comment: NetBeans->Tools->Plugins->Installed, check Show details, then find Gluon Plugin, and see the version number. If it is lower than 2.8.3 you can update it. Then I suggest you start a new project.

Comment: @JoséPereda after restarting my computer and trying those steps, it does in fact say that the plugin is version 2.8.3. I have attached the new full error statement in the question since it seems to have changed.

Comment: The error is clear: there is no client-maven-plugin:1.0.3. As I said before, either you replace *client-maven-plugin* with *gluonfx-maven-plugin* in your pom,  or you start a new project with the updated Gluon IDE plugin.

Comment: I see, @JoséPereda. I misunderstood what you said. I updated the pom so that client-maven-plugin is changed to gluonfx-maven-plugin. Now `mvn gluonfx:run` works, but `mvn gluonfx:build` doesn't. See the question for that error.

Comment: You need to read the error messages, they are usually self-explanatory. Did you install GraalVM? I suggest you take a look at https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_macos.

Comment: @JoséPereda I did read it but am confused because I did install GraalVM. I followed the instructions on https://foojay.io/today/creating-mobile-apps-with-javafx-part-2/: Next, set environment variable GRAALVM_HOME to the GraalVM JDK:

`$ export GRAALVM_HOME=/path/to/graalvm-svm-darwin-gluon-21.1.0-dev/Contents/Home` I am going to redo the process and let you know what happens

Comment: The link I posted shows a more recent GraalVM version: 21.2.0. Also you need to use the exact path of your GraalVM local installation, not the literal "/path/to".

Comment: @JoséPereda it is working now with 21.1.0. I didn't see your comment until after I had set it up, but it seems to be fine with the slightly later version. My problem now that I have been trying to troubleshoot is `Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "s" is null` with `mvn -Pios gluonfx:build`. I'm not sure what that is because it is not relating to my actual code. I have put the full error in the question.

Comment: Can you run from a terminal `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path` and post the result?

Comment: The result has been posted, @JoséPereda.

Comment: That doesn't look good, does it? You need Xcode. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @JoséPereda I do. In fact, I have an Apple Developer Account as well as an Xcode project named after my Gluon project. I currently am running the Xcode project on my iPhone, which I have plugged into my mac.

Comment: Ok, good. Can you run from terminal `xcode-select -p`, it should point to your Xcode app.

Comment: @JoséPereda it points to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools. Is that normal? CommandLineTools is not the name of my project.

Comment: CommandLineTools is a very lite version of Xcode. You need to run: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Ok, @JoséPereda. That worked!`xcode-select -p` now points to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk`. I am rerunning the build and run sequences to test on my iPhone; I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @JoséPereda everything is working well so far, however I noticed that the terminal says `Default iOS plist generated in /Users/superpengooooo/NetBeansProjects/Therabot/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/gensrc/ios/Default-Info.plist.
Consider copying it to /Users/superpengooooo/NetBeansProjects/Therabot/src/ios before performing any modification`, however there is no 'ios' file in my src file. Is this a problem, should I make an ios file, or can I proceed without one?

Comment: No needed, unless you want to customize either plist file or assets. Something for later probably

Comment: @JoséPereda I have good and bad news. The good news is that it deployed to my iPhone, which is great!!! However, the bad news is that I am getting errors with the code itself when I perform actions in the app that I have never received before. Could you take a look at the error statements that I am receiving as well as my GitHub Repo for reference (if needed)? https://github.com/5-pengoo/Therabot Thank you so much.

Comment: Does the app run fine on desktop (`mvn javafx:run`)? You can test it and fix it faster, and then deploy again

Comment: @JoséPereda it did run properly on the desktop, which is why I asked you. Normally, I would be able to debug, but I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Can you run, `mvn gluonfx:runagent`? And then build and deploy again

Comment: @JoséPereda actually, I also noticed that the image that I have set to be in the background of the app on startup is not showing. Either there are multiple issues when deploying to ios, or maybe this is grabbing an old version of my code that used to not work? I don't know, but `mvn javafx:run` as well as running from my IDE works.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'll try that. Do I terminate processes from running by just closing the terminal, or can I do it without closing the terminal?

Comment: Ctrl+C from terminal to stop the maven process

Comment: @JoséPereda I followed the steps you mentioned, and now my iPhone screen is blank. I can't get out of the app. I have attached an image of this in the question.

Comment: What do you get in the condole? There should be some indication of a possible error

Comment: @JoséPereda actually, yes, I just noticed `[Sat Aug 07 16:32:11 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] error: timed out waiting for app to launch
[Sat Aug 07 16:32:11 PDT 2021][INFO] [SUB] (lldb)     autoexit`, which makes since because I had to open the app myself; it didn't automatically open like normal. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @JoséPereda I stopped the maven process, however, the app won't close. I can only turn my phone on and off, and visit the notification center. When I try to power it off, it only buzzes alarmingly. I can also not visit other apps by tapping on them in the notification center.

Comment: Just unplug your phone and plug it again, then run `mvn -Pios gluonfx:nativerun`

Comment: Never seen anything like that. Long press the app to uninstall it and then install again?

Comment: @JoséPereda it's giving a similar, if not the same error. I noticed something new this time, but I don't know if I didn't see it because it was pushed away by new error messages or if it legitimately wasn't there. I have added it to the question.

Comment: @JoséPereda after unplugging the phone, it stopped doing that. I might try deleting the app, though, just to see if it fixes anything.

Comment: The error with the png is clear, “src/main/resources” is not a valid URL

Comment: (Remove your license number from the post...)

Comment: @JoséPereda thank you for catching that. I'll delete it now

Comment: @JoséPereda can I not store images in that resource file  (src/main/resources) to be accessed in the app?

Comment: You can, but with the correct url. “/src/main/resources” should be removed. (I can look into these errors tomorrow)

Comment: @JoséPereda I removed "/src/main/resources", but it still didn't work. Also, it looks like the reason why the screen was white and glitching was because I didn't delete the app off of my iPhone, since I forgot to delete it, and it did it again. Anyways, if you must go, thank you so much for your time thus far, and I look forward to hearing from you tomorrow!

Comment: I have done some small fixes, and you have now a few Pull Requests pending.

Comment: @JoséPereda wow, thank you so much! While I am merging things, could you explain what you did in the json file? I see that it is for adding "config files for native-image", but could you go into a bit more depth? I'm not too familiar with json but am curious for future Gluon and other projects.

Comment: I just ran `mvn gluonfx:runagent`, it automatically generates these json files. See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_goals for more details.

Comment: @JoséPereda Ok, so I merged and pulled all changes and am now getting some errors. See the GitHub repo.

Comment: Did you remove the repository??

Comment: @JoséPereda so sorry, you should be able to see it now. Some things got messed up.